# Trying to figure out how to update hidden input with value from select in Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm having a very hard time wrapping my head around this one.  I am using KnockoutJS and I have a select dropdown that is observable.  When I change the value of that dropdown, I want it to change a hidden input one per row in my table.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to set that value in the subscribe function.  I know the subscribe function is getting called because my console output runs.

Here is my HTML select and part of my table that has the hidden input I want changed:

```
<div data-bind="if: (availableProfitCodes().length > 1)">
                <select id="profitCode" data-bind="value: selectedProfitCode, options: availableProfitCodes, optionsText: function(code) { return code.name + ' : ' + code.desc }, optionsValue: 'code', optionsCaption: '-- select a profit code --'"></select>
            </div>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: codes">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input data-bind="value: itemNo, attr: { name: 'brochureProfitCodes[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureProfitCodes_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" />
                        <input data-bind="value: profitCode, attr: {name: 'brochureProfitCodes[' + $index() + '].profitCode', id: 'brochureProfitCodes_' + $index() + '__profitCode' }" type="hidden" class="profitCode" />
                    </td>
```

And my knockout code (the part not working is in the subscribe function):

```
var CodeModel = function(data) {
        var self = this;

        self.profitCode = ko.observable(data ? data.profitCode : '');

        self.itemNo = data.itemNo;
        self.brocCode = data.brocCode;
        self.brochureID = data.brochureID;
        self.itemDesc = data.itemDesc;
        self.retail = data.retail;
        self.wholesale = data.wholesale;
        self.commission = data.commission;
    }

    var codesModel = function(codes) {
        var self = this;
        self.availableProfitCodes = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.selectedProfitCode = ko.observable();

        //self.codes = ko.observableArray(codes);
        //self.codes = ko.observable(new CodeModel());
        if(codes != null) {
            self.codes = ko.observableArray(codes.map(function(code) { return new CodeModel(code) }));
        }            

        self.selectedProfitCode.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            console.log("newValue is: " + newValue);
            self.codes.profitCode(newValue);
        });
    };
$(document).ready(function () {

        var profitCodeInt = Number($.trim($("#pCode").val()));
        if(profitCodeInt == 0) { // adding a new profit code
            ...
        }
        else if(profitCodeInt > 0) { // editing an existing profit code
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetProfitCodesJSON", "Brochure")',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(json) {
                    var codesJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.brochureProfitCodes));
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(codesJSON));
                    var itemsJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.brochureItems));
                    viewModel = new codesModel(codesJSON);
                    var result = json.profitCodes.filter(function( obj ) {
                        return obj.profitCode == profitCodeInt;
                    });
                    var code = new profitCode(result[0].profitCode, result[0].profitDesc, result[0].profitName);
                    viewModel.availableProfitCodes.push(code);
                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#profitModal")[0]);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You've got a few versions of codesModel.codes in there so I'm not certain what you're currently using, but I think codes is supposed to be an array? if so you just need to loop through each item and set the item's profitCode rather than setting profitCode on the collection itself. for(var x=0; x<self.codes().length; x++){ self.codes()[x].profitCode(newValue); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.codes` is an `observableArray` so u need to use `self.codes()` and loop through

```js
var CodeModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.profitCode = ko.observable(data ? data.profitCode : '');

  self.itemNo = data.itemNo;
  self.brocCode = data.brocCode;
  self.brochureID = data.brochureID;
  self.itemDesc = data.itemDesc;
  self.retail = data.retail;
  self.wholesale = data.wholesale;
  self.commission = data.commission;
}

var codesModel = function(codes) {
  var self = this;
  self.availableProfitCodes = ko.observableArray(options);
  self.selectedProfitCode = ko.observable();

  //self.codes = ko.observableArray(codes);
  //self.codes = ko.observable(new CodeModel());
  if (codes != null) {
    self.codes = ko.observableArray(codes.map(function(code) {
      return new CodeModel(code)
    }));
  }

  self.selectedProfitCode.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    self.codes().forEach(function(code) { code.profitCode(newValue); });
  });
};

var initCodes = [{ profitCode: 'ABC', itemNo: 1}, { profitCode: 'DEF', itemNo: 2 }];
var options = [
  { name: 1, desc: 'one', code: 'IJK' }, 
  { name: 2, desc: 'two', code: 'LMN' },
  { name: 3, desc: 'three', code: 'OPQ' }
];

ko.applyBindings(new codesModel(initCodes));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="if: (availableProfitCodes().length > 1)">
  <select id="profitCode" data-bind="value: selectedProfitCode, options: availableProfitCodes, optionsText: function(code) { return code.name + ' : ' + code.desc }, optionsValue: 'code', optionsCaption: '-- select a profit code --'"></select>
</div>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: codes">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input data-bind="value: itemNo, attr: { name: 'brochureProfitCodes[' + $index() + '].itemNo', id: 'brochureProfitCodes_' + $index() + '__itemNo' }, validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"
        tabindex="-1" />
        <input data-bind="value: profitCode, attr: {name: 'brochureProfitCodes[' + $index() + '].profitCode', id: 'brochureProfitCodes_' + $index() + '__profitCode' }" type="hidden" class="profitCode" /><span data-bind="text: profitCode"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thank you very much!